# variable name meaning in arduino library

Tags: variables, arduino

Can someone help me here to understand about arduino library variable name like what is tempTC, tempCJC,  faultOpen, faultShortGND, faultShortVCC,

I am so confused. please help here ! thanks

/*
    read_MAX31855.ino

```
TODO:
        Clean up code and comment!!
        Also make use of all library functions and make more robust.
This work is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported License.
http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/
*/

#include <MAX31855.h>

// Adruino 1.0 pre-defines these variables
#if ARDUINO < 100
int SCK = 13;
int MISO = 12;
int SS = 10;
#endif
int LED = 9;

// Setup the variables we are going to use.
double tempTC, tempCJC;
bool faultOpen, faultShortGND, faultShortVCC, x;
bool temp_unit = 1; // 0 = Celsius, 1 = Fahrenheit

// Init the MAX31855 library for the chip.
MAX31855 temp(SCK, SS, MISO);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  x = temp.readMAX31855(&tempTC, &tempCJC, &faultOpen, &faultShortGND, &faultShortVCC, temp_unit);

    Serial.print(tempTC);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print(tempCJC);
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.print(faultOpen);
    Serial.print(faultShortGND);
    Serial.println(faultShortVCC);

  digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
  delay(500);
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/ryanjmclaughlin/MAX31855_Library

Answer (score 1):

- `tempTC`: The thermocouple value read from the IC.
- `tempCJC`: The Cold Junction-Compensated temperature value.
- `faultOpen` `faultShortGND` `faultShortVCC`: Flags that indicate wether any of these faults occurred while reading the temperature.

All these are done directly in the `MAX31855` IC, read via SPI with the library you posted.